# Configure connection timeout of pacman full system upgrade

Tags: upgrade, pacman, manjaro

Is there a way to **set the timeout** which [`pacman`](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Pacman_Overview) uses to establish connections to repository servers? My ISP (university) has blocked several Arch Linux (I use [Manjaro](http://manjaro.org/)) `AUR` and a few `community` servers. I want to reduce the timeout, so that 70% of the "download" ends faster, even though some packages are missing. I can get the remaining packages via a slow (trusted) proxy service.

Whenever I start an upgrade `pacman` tries *too hard* to download all packages. `pacman` tries all Arch mirror servers for each package, and this consumes too much time. I know that all these servers are going to timeout for the 30% *"blocked"* packages.

I don't want to maintain a list of packages that are going to be *blocked* (even though the list doesn't vary much). This is the behaviour I would like:

- `pacman` should quickly download the 70% *unblocked* ones and then `upgrade` would fail *(because some packages are missing)*.
- After enabling the proxy, I'd re-run `pacman -Su` and the `upgrade` would get completed.

Specifically these are the errors shown by `pacman`. I couldn't find any command-line switch for setting timeout.

```
error: failed retrieving "file" from "server" : Resolving timed out after 10520 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving "file" from "server" : Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
error: failed retrieving "file" from "server" : Could not resolve host: "server"
```

Or maybe I should setup some scripts to keep track of the packages that seemed to be *blocked* in the previous `upgrade`, and defer their downloads in the end?

That still doesn't solve the original problem as there could be a *"new blocked"* package when I upgrade *this* time. Deffered downloads would also take an eternity because of the large timeouts.

> `pacman-mirrors` list is always up to date. It gets synced with every upgrade *(anyways)*.

Comment: Use a tool like [Reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reflector) to only query known good mirrors (and a limited subset thereof)...

Comment: So, to be clear, it's not the mirrors that are blocked, but only certain *files*?

Comment: Not possible; if you have access to the mirror, you have access to all the repos on it...

Comment: It's been a long time, and I enjoyed unrestricted internet for these months... and was away from this problem :).
I will be going back to my university and I'll post better analysis with the install logs to find which files or servers fail.  

@XiongChiamiov I know just a few files blocked sounds crazy, I find it hard to believe myself and probably I've been wrong in assuming that.

Comment: @jasonwryan Reflector is a great tool, it did speed up my downloads, but my problem remains.

Comment: @jasonwryan It definitely is possible; for instance, proxies sometimes block urls that contain words in a blacklist to cut down on their users accessing porn or piracy sites.